# How to validate multiple drop down list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

#### HTML :

```
<select type="text" class="que_ans" name="answer[12]" id="answer_12" size="1">
    <option value="0" selected> -- Select Response -- </option>
    <option value="1">Not Satisfied</option>
    <option value="2">Somewhat Satisfied</option>
</select>

<select type="text" class="que_ans" name="answer[13]" id="answer_13" size="1">
    <option value="0" selected> -- Select Response -- </option>
    <option value="1">Not Satisfied</option>
    <option value="2">Somewhat Satisfied</option>
</select>
```

How to validate the drop down list using array name `answer[12]` ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "validate the drop down list in same name using array name "?

Comment: you can validate them through their ids

Comment: I'm just a computer, "validate drop-downs through their ids " means nothing to me.

Comment: how to get ids using throught the class name, I did below like this $('.que_ans :selected').each(function(i, selected){  $(".que_ans option:selected").attr(id) });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class and title attributes on your dropdown element like:

```
    <select  type="text" class="que_ans required" name="answer[12]" id="answer_12" size="1" title="This is required field" >
    <option value="0" selected> -- Select Response -- </option>
    <option value="1">Not Satisfied</option>
    <option value="2">Somewhat Satisfied</option>
</select>
<select  type="text" class="que_ans required" name="answer[13]" id="answer_13" size="1" title="This is required field">
    <option value="0" selected> -- Select Response -- </option>
    <option value="1">Not Satisfied</option>
    <option value="2">Somewhat Satisfied</option>
</select>
```

And add following script at the end of your page

```
<script>
   $('select.required').each(function () {
        var message = $(this).attr('title');
        if($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == 0) {                
              alert(message);
              $(this).focus();
              breakout = true;
              return false;
        }

    }
});
</script>
```

I hope, it will fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you could use attribute selector `$(select[name="answer[12]"])` for specific ones

or more generic `$(select[name])` to select all `<select>` with name attribute.

also `val()` method can be used for the getting the selected item.

eg: `$(select[name="answer[12]"]).val()`